# Divide loop iteration in an html.erb file over different sections for enhancing performance

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is part of my code in an html.erb file

```
<div class="list_carousel">
  <ul id="products-carousel" class="carousel">
    <% @posts.select{ |post| post.categories.include?(@categories.find_by_name("Productos")) }.each do |post|%>
      [...]
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
[...]
<div class="modals">
  <% @posts.select{ |post| post.categories.include?(@categories.find_by_name("Productos")) }.each do |post|%>
    [...]
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The problem here is that I'm using several database queries to perform this loop and I would like to re-use the first loop in other parts of this files in order to enhance performance.

For example I would like to do something like each do |post| do something in this first section, don't do nothing in this second section and continue in the third one. This way I could re-use the instance of the selected postd over which I'm iterating.

Comment: First thing you want to do is move that query to the controller. The view is for template code, not for queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you can do this:

```
@posts              = Post.all
@productos_category = @categories.where(name: "Productos").first
@productos          = @posts.where(category_id: @productos_category.id)
```

Note that I changed the way you find the associated `@productos` to use the ActiveRecord query interface, as opposed to using pure ruby `select` and `include?` methods.  This will allow for the query to be much more efficient.  I implied some things, such as the child key for the categories being `category_id`.  Change this where appropriate.

**EDIT 1**

I believe this will work, although my experience with many-to-many relationships is somewhat limited:

```
@productos_category = @categories.where(name: "Productos").first
@productos_posts    = Post.joins(:join_table).where(join_table: {category_id: @productos_category.id})
```

Where `:join_table` is the name of the table that is used in the has_many association.  If it is a HABTM relationship, this will probably be called `categories_posts`.

Then your view would change to this:

```
<div class="list_carousel">
  <ul id="products-carousel" class="carousel">
    <% @productos_posts.each do |post|%>
      [...]
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
[...]
<div class="modals">
  <% @productos_posts.each do |post|%>
    [...]
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem is that Post and Category models have a many-to-many asocciation... so I need to look in category_ids

Comment: This is a good advice, but it doesn't answer the question. He wanna now (depite how he's going to acquire it) how he could loop only once, and have both `list_carousel` and `modals` div populated is this single loop.

Comment: I dont believe that is true.  I believe he only phrased the question that way in the interest of performance.  Once the queries are fixed, the way he is doing it presently would work fine.

Comment: @tomascharad give me a sec, and I will update my answer with the proper way to do this for a many-to-many

Comment: @tomascharad is it a `has_and_belongs_to_many` or a `has_many through:` relationship?

Comment: @Eugene it is a has_many through association "has_many :categorizations, dependent: :destroy" "has_many :categories, through: :categorizations"

Comment: Thanks @Eugene! Even that it wasn't what I initialy asked, it helped me to finally understand how active record interface really works and why my site was so inefficient.